# Hide tablix in SSRS based on parameter value

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I need to hide a tablix in SSRS based on the value of a parameter. My parameter is set to text values and there are two possible values (X and Y). If X and Y are selected, I want the tablix to show. I also need the tablix to show if X selected, and then be hidden if Y is selected.

I have this expression written:

```
=IIF
(Join(Parameters!Action.Value())="XY",TRUE,
IIF(Parameters!Action.Value)="X",TRUE,FALSE)
```

But I am getting this error:
The Visibility.Hidden expression for the tablix ‘Tablix1’ contains an error: [BC30516] Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IIf' accepts this number of arguments.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you just have a `)` in the wrong place

```
=IIF( 
    Join(Parameters!Action.Value())="XY",
    TRUE,
    IIF(Parameters!Action.Value="X",
       TRUE,
       FALSE)
    )
```